# Некорректное отображение шрифта Cuprum

Tags: java, swing

У текста в `JLabel` при установленном шрифте [Cuprum](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cuprum), размера **15px**, видны явные графические дефекты. При этом, если задать размер шрифта **24px**, они пропадают. Проблема непосредственно с этим шрифтом, остальные отображаются нормально. Как это можно решить?

[image: JLabel Cuprum]

Comment: Попробуйте значение свойства [awt.useSystemAAFontSettings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts) поменять, может что-то даст.

Comment: @zRrr, нет, к сожалению, это ничего не дает.